# Finding the shape which gives the max area with constraint.

Tags: optimization

The problem is:

> Given $x$ feet of material with one side being $y$ long, what shape gives the maximum area that can be enclosed.

My solution is having the $y$ side a straight line, and having a curve that is semi-circular as possible to the end points of the line $Y$ (the line that is $y$ long). But, $y$ has to be small enough that $x-y > y$ thus, then there is enough lenght to connect the end points of the line $Y$.

I think this is the best solutions because from my own work the circle has the best edge length to area.

I am asking here because last week, my friend gave me the problem of connecting houses to  water lines on a sheet of paper, without any pipes crossing and cutting the paper.  The solution was folding the paper like a doughnut, was a complete surprise to me.

That is why I am asking here, is there something I missed? I have also checked the *Questions that may already have your answer* and the internet.

**Edit**  Gerry Myerson gave a great counter example, thus my solution doesn't always work. Yet, there has to exist a curve that connects the ends of the line that is $y$ long.

Comment: Is this a rectangle of material of size $x \times y$?  Are you allowed to cut it?

Comment: @Henry , I will ask after break, but I think it is just like I have a pile of material that is $x$ long, and one side has to be $y$ long.  But, if you have a solution for an $x \times y$ plane, that would be awesome, as well.  Post your solution, and I'll upvote as long as I don't find an error. hehe

Comment: The trouble with having $x-y$ as an arc is that it may be geometrically impossible, e.g., if $x=100$ and $y=99$ you can't make any shape, arc or no.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter I am not trying to be rude, but could you please explain how "area of the enclosed shape" is ambiguous.